# Kafka Snowflake ConnectStandalone - Error while starting the Snowflake connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

[image]

```
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkTask[ID:0]:start. Time: 0 seconds (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkTask:154)
[2021-09-07 23:19:44,145] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=snowflakeslink-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:309)
[2021-09-07 23:19:44,169] WARN [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-snowflakeslink-0, groupId=connect-snowflakeslink] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:769)
[2021-09-07 23:19:44,170] WARN [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-snowflakeslink-0, groupId=connect-snowflakeslink] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1060)
```

Comment: `terminated during authentication` ... Does your broker actually use authentication? Please show all relevant property files (server.properties, connect-standalone, and your connector config)

Comment: No, there is nothing in the broker for authentication.

Comment: I have enclosed properties files in the main issues posted as image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxSzP.png

Comment: 1) In the standalone properties what happens when you remove `consumer.security.protocol` and `ssl.client.auth`? 2) In the connector, remove the `schema.registry.url` since you're not using Confluent-based converters. 3) Dont store your connector plugins inside the kafka libs folder since these will conflict with the actual broker classpath

Comment: I removed the consumer.security.protocol and ssl.client.auth from standalone properties and removed the schema.registry.url from connector properties. But as you said the third point not storing the plugins inside the kafka libs, where these needs to be stored? As I tried storing it in the java libs folder. But it didnt work

Comment: Literally any other folder, then update `plugin.path` accordingly. But that is unrelated to your error here

Comment: ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}

Comment: After moving the connector JAR file to Java home and declaring the same in Server.properties and Connector properties

Comment: You shouldn't put things in "JAVA_HOME" either. Create `/opt/kafka-connect-plugins`, set that as your plugin path, move the folder for the snowflake connector there (as a subfolder). Once again, though, that's not really relevant to the error you've originally posted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> Connection ...  terminated during authentication

You need to remove `consumer.security.protocol=SSL` in your connect-standalone.properties since your broker's `server.properties` `listener` is not using SSL

Your next error

> Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector

Look at the list, it indeed doesn't exist, which means you've not correctly extracted the Snowflake connector libraries into the `plugin.path`, which should be a folder that is external to Kafka's internal `lib` folder, for example `plugin.path=/opt/kafka-connectors/`, with a subfolder for `snowflake` containing all its needed JARs. This way, it will not conflict with the actual classpath of the broker and other Kafka/Zookeeper CLI tools that rely on this folder

Comment: Additionally, `localhost:9092` is a Kafka address, probably, not a Schema Registry, so your connector config is incorrect as well